# Modern Algebra: Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Is this the way to solve the question?

Question a). Find the center of the group $S_3 \times  \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$

Ans: $S_3$is the order of 6 element therefore, {1,(12),(23),(13),(123),(132)} and
$\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is the integer with modulo of 6 (13 modulo 6 =1). The Center will be 1.

Question b). Show that for n > 2 the group $S_n$ is not cyclic, but can be generated
by two elements.

Ans: 
1)  The group $S_n$ consists of all the bijective functions from the set 
{1, 2, ..., n} to itself.  The group operation in $S_n$ is composition 
of functions.  "Bijective" means one-to-one and onto.  In particular, 
if F is an element of Sn and x and y are different elements of
{1, 2, ..., n}, then F(x) and F(y) are not equal.

2)  If n is at least 3, then $S_n$ contains the following two functions 
(and more):

The function A whose values are given by A(1) = 2, A(2) = 1, and
A(x) = x when x is not 1 or 2.

The function B whose values are given by B(1) = 1, B(2) = 3, 
B(3) = 2, and B(x) = x for x not equal to 2 or 3.

3)  We can compose these functions.

```
AB is the function whose values are given as follows:
   (AB)(1) = A(B(1)) = A(1) = 2
   (AB)(2) = A(B(2)) = A(3) = 3
   (AB)(3) = A(B(3)) = A(2) = 1
   (AB)(x) = A(B(x)) = A(x) = x  if x is not 1, 2, or 3

BA is the function whose values are given as
   (BA)(1) = B(A(1)) = B(2) = 3
   (BA)(2) = B(A(2)) = B(1) = 1
   (BA)(3) = B(A(3)) = B(3) = 2
   (BA)(x) = B(A(x)) = B(x) = x  if x is not 1, 2, or 3
```

4) Therefore it's not abelian, it cannot be cyclic.

---

Help me understand it better if I am wrong with an explanation.

Comment: For direct products, $Z(G\times H)=Z(G)\times Z(H)$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:  So then how will be the answer. Help me to find my confusion. What about second question.

Comment: What you wrote in (a) as "ans." is just a claim without any explanation and proof. It is wrong, by the way, but the point is that students are usually expected to provide proofs for their work.

Comment: I have two question I got it for question a but I wanted to know whether I am right for question b

Comment: Your part (b) looks correct but it'd help a lot if you could write it down using LaTeXMathJax as usual in this site.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)

The center of a group G, Z(G), is the set of all elements in G that are commutative with all elements in G. In a sense it is the "abelian part" of a group. If a group is abelian, then the center is the group itself, since the group is commutative. So there is more than just the identity in Z(GxH) in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help for question but what about question 2? Is that right?